# Javascript in custom content plugin output

Tags: joomla-2.5, php, plugin, javascript, content

I want to use javascript in my custom Joomla content plugin, but I can't get my custom text when type text in my input by using `getElementById`.

My code is:

```
<?php
    $output = '
        <input type="text" id="name" value="default" />
        <button onclick="myAlert();" >test code</button>
        <script>
            var myText = document.getElementById("name").value;
            function myAlert(){
                alert(myText);
            } 
        </script>
        ';
?>
```

When I click the button only alert default value and not my custom name.

How can I do this?

Comment: check console for any errors

Comment: I found my problem it's simple. I must placed var myText inside the function. now it's work

Comment: Please add an answer with your working code, it might help other users later.

Answer (score 2):

I found my problem it's simple. I must placed var myText inside the function. now it's work
this code work:

```
<?php
$output = '
    <input type="text" id="name" value="default" />
    <button onclick="myAlert();" >test code</button>
    <script>
        function myAlert(){
            var myText = document.getElementById("name").value;
            alert(myText);
        } 
    </script>
    ';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check **JDocument** functions to add scripts to the page output:

- [JDocument/addScriptDeclaration](https://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScriptDeclaration)
- [JDocument/addScript](https://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScript)